# How do i get the query searched on google, when people visits my page?

Tags: php, web, seo

As the title states, i try to find a way to see what search words people used on google when they entered my website.

e.g:

1. a person, searches for "cheap cloth" on google
2. my link pops-up on google
3. my link is pressed, and he is redirected to my homepage
4. I want to know WHAT word he used to find my website

It seems like its no longer possible with just pure code (php), since google switched to HTTPS.

But isn't their any other ways to find out? Don't google have an API, that I can use to find out stuff like that?

Comment: a) ask your visitors b) use webmaster tools or analytics

Comment: #donald123 You say Webmaster tools or Analytics, can you point me in direction (URL) to some API's for this?
I would like to get it on my webpage :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register on "[Google Search Console](https://google.com/webmasters)"

Once you verified your website, you can see the stats

If you already registered on Google Search Console your can see your stats in "Search Analytics"